Unable to update user profile using PUT method (Django DRF)
I am currently working on a mentor-mentee matching service using Django DRF. I have made a 'users' app and have completed creating users&logging in. But I can't edit user info using PUT method.
Here are my project files (models.py, serializers.py, views.py, urls.py, settings.py)
1. models.py
# users/models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator


class User(AbstractUser):
  is_mentor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics/', default = 'default.png') # profile_pic dir 만들기, default이미지 업로드하기, 사진 첨부 루트 만들기
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name= ("이름"))
  birth_date = models.DateField(verbose_name= ("생년월일"), null=True, blank=True)
  agreed_to_terms = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name= ("이용약관 동의"))
  @property
  def role(self):
    return "Mentor" if self.is_mentor else "Mentee"

class Interest(models.Model):
  INTEREST_CHOICES = (
    ('belief', '가치관'),
    ('finance', '재테크'),
    ('love', '사랑'),
    ('daily', '생활 지식'),
    ('relationship', '인간 관계'),
    ('career', '진로'),
  )
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=INTEREST_CHOICES, unique=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.get_name_display()

class Mentor(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='mentor')
  interests = models.ManyToManyField(Interest, through='MentorInterest')
  rating = models.FloatField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(5)])
  total_ratings = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
  
  def clean(self):
    super().clean()
    if self.interests.count() > 3:
        raise ValidationError("mentors can choose under 3 interest.")
  def update_rating(self, new_rating):
    self.rating = ((self.rating * self.total_ratings) + new_rating) / (self.total_ratings + 1)
    self.total_ratings += 1
    self.save()

class MentorInterest(models.Model):
  mentor = models.ForeignKey(Mentor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  interest = models.ForeignKey(Interest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  
  class Meta:
    unique_together = ('mentor', 'interest')
  def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.mentor.user.username} - {self.interest.name}'

class Mentee(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='mentee')

2. serializers.py
# serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User, Mentor, Mentee, Interest, MentorInterest

class InterestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Interest
    fields = ['name']

class MentorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  # Write-only field to receive interests as choice names
  interests = serializers.ListField(
    child=serializers.ChoiceField(choices=[choice[0] for choice in Interest.INTEREST_CHOICES]),  # 선택 항목의 키 값만 사용
    write_only=True
  )

  # Read-only field to display interests
  interests_display = InterestSerializer(source='interests', many=True, read_only=True)

  class Meta:
    model = Mentor
    fields = [
      'interests',
      'interests_display',
      'rating',
      'total_ratings'
    ]

  def validate_interests(self, value):
    if len(value) > 3:
      raise serializers.ValidationError("멘토는 3개 이하의 관심사를 선택할 수 있습니다.")
    # Check if each interest exists in the database
    for interest_name in value:
      if not Interest.objects.filter(name=interest_name).exists():
        raise serializers.ValidationError(f"관심사 '{interest_name}'가 유효하지 않습니다.")
    return value

class MenteeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  
  class Meta:
    model = Mentee
    fields = []

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  mentor_profile = MentorSerializer(required=False)
  mentee_profile = MenteeSerializer(required=False)

  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
      'id',
      'username',
      'email',
      'password',
      'is_mentor',
      'name',
      'birth_date',
      'profile_pic',
      'agreed_to_terms',
      'mentor_profile',
      'mentee_profile'
    ]
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

  def create(self, validated_data):
    # Extract nested profile data
    mentor_data = validated_data.pop('mentor_profile', None)
    mentee_data = validated_data.pop('mentee_profile', None)

    # Create user object with hashed password
    user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

    # Handle mentor creation
    if user.is_mentor and mentor_data:
      interests_data = mentor_data.pop('interests', [])
      mentor = Mentor.objects.create(user=user, **mentor_data)
      # Set up interests through MentorInterest
      for interest_name in interests_data:
        interest = Interest.objects.get(name=interest_name)
        MentorInterest.objects.create(mentor=mentor, interest=interest)

    # Handle mentee creation
    elif not user.is_mentor and mentee_data:
      # 멘티는 카테고리를 설정하지 않는다는 새로운 설정!
      Mentee.objects.create(user=user, **mentee_data)

    return user

  def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    mentor_data = validated_data.pop('mentor_profile', None)
    mentee_data = validated_data.pop('mentee_profile', None)

    # 유저 속성들 업데이트 (차후에 업데이트 가능한 속성을 더 넣고 싶다면 추가 가능)
    instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
    instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
    instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
    instance.birth_date = validated_data.get('birth_date', instance.birth_date)
    instance.profile_pic = validated_data.get('profile_pic', instance.profile_pic)
    instance.save()
    
    # Update mentor profile if the user is a mentor
    if instance.is_mentor and mentor_data:
      mentor_serializer = MentorSerializer(instance.mentor_profile, data=mentor_data, partial=True)
      if mentor_serializer.is_valid():
        mentor_serializer.save()

    # Update mentee profile if the user is not a mentor
    elif not instance.is_mentor and mentee_data:
      mentee_serializer = MenteeSerializer(instance.mentee_profile, data=mentee_data, partial=True)
      if mentee_serializer.is_valid():
        mentee_serializer.save()
    return instance

3. views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

# 회원가입
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .models import User, Mentor, Mentee, Interest
from .serializers import UserSerializer, MentorSerializer, MenteeSerializer, InterestSerializer

from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated

from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
  def validate(self, attrs):
    data = super().validate(attrs)

    # 사용자에 대한 추가 정보를 JWT 페이로드에 포함
    data['user_id'] = self.user.id
    data['username'] = self.user.username
    data['is_mentor'] = self.user.is_mentor
    data['name'] = self.user.name

    return data


class CustomTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer

# 로그아웃 뷰
class LogoutView(APIView):
  permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]  # 로그인된 사용자만 접근 가능

  def post(self, request):
    # Refresh 토큰을 요청 데이터에서 추출
    refresh_token = request.data.get("refresh")
    
    if not refresh_token:
      return Response({"detail": "Refresh token is required."}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    try:
      # RefreshToken 객체 생성 및 블랙리스트에 추가
      token = RefreshToken(refresh_token)
      token.blacklist()
      return Response(status=status.HTTP_205_RESET_CONTENT)
    except Exception as e:
      return Response({"detail": str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = User.objects.all()
  serializer_class = UserSerializer
  def get_permissions(self):
    if self.action == 'create':
      permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    else:
      permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]

  def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
    if response.status_code == status.HTTP_201_CREATED:
      response.data['message'] = "User created successfully!"
    return response
  
  def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # 본인만 자신의 정보를 업데이트할 수 있도록 함
    if request.user.id != kwargs.get('pk'):
      return Response({"detail": "로그인 후 정보 수정하시길 바랍니다."}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
    response = super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)
    if response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK:
      response.data['message'] = "유저 정보 수정 성공"
    return response

  def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # 본인만 자신의 정보를 업데이트할 수 있도록 함
    if request.user.id != kwargs.get('pk'):
      return Response({"detail": "로그인 후 정보 수정하시길 바랍니다."}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
    
    response = super().partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
    if response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK:
      response.data['message'] = "유저 정보 부분 수정 성공"
    return response

4. urls.py
(project/urls.py)
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

# ImageField를 위해
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

# 로그인을 위해
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),  # 로그인 엔드포인트
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),  # 토큰 갱신 엔드포인트
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

(users/urls.py)

from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from .views import UserViewSet, CustomTokenObtainPairView, LogoutView

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('login/', CustomTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),  # 로그인 엔드포인트
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),  # 로그아웃 엔드포인트
]

Also I put a file in Migration folder to initialize Interests
# Generated by Django 5.0.7 on 2024-07-29 12:38
# users/migrations/0002_add_initial_interests.py

from django.db import migrations

def create_initial_interests(apps, schema_editor):
    Interest = apps.get_model('users', 'Interest')
    interests = [
        ('belief', '가치관'),
        ('finance', '재테크'),
        ('love', '사랑'),
        ('daily', '생활 지식'),
        ('relationship', '인간 관계'),
        ('career', '진로'),
    ]
    for name, display_name in interests:
        Interest.objects.get_or_create(name=name)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('users', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_initial_interests),
    ]

I have...

Logged into the user that I wanted to change info : /users/login/
Copied the access token and put it in the Authorization header
/users/users/<user_id>/ using PUT method gave me 403 error


There are two immediate areas you should investigate for what's triggering the 403. The first is get_permissions() - add some debugging of whatever style you prefer and check that the permission check actually succeeds for your user. If it doesn't, your authentication schema is the issue. Next is UserViewSet.update() - debug whether the id of the user and pk from kwargs are a match or not (and then compare to whether it should be a match or not).

First, if the client tries to modify the user's information through HTTP method PUT
IsAuthentication is assigned to permission_classes.
An authentication process is required to proceed with the permission check.
However, UserViewSet does not specify authentication_classes related to the authentication process.
(Of course, the questioner's settings.py It may be defined in.
But for now, I decided there wasn't one.)
That's why I first assigned IsAuthenticated to UserViewSet as authentication_classes.
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    ...

Next, if you look at the update method that will be called when using PUT
, request.user.id and kwargs.get('pk') will be used in the if statement.
But this if expression can never be established.
This is because the types of the two values are different.
request.user.id  --> type int
kwargs.get('pk') --> type str

As shown above, the value of request.user.id is int type and kwargs.get ('pk') is str type.
That's why you need to convert one of the two values so that the two types are the same.
like this
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # 본인만 자신의 정보를 업데이트할 수 있도록 함
    
    if request.user.id != int(kwargs.get('pk')):
        return Response({"detail": "로그인 후 정보 수정하시길 바랍니다."},    status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

When I modified the two, I confirmed that the PUT works well.

In addition, implementing has_object_permission in the permission class when object-level inspection is required is a good solution.
Please refer to this document
